# Dropdown not placing correct in modal header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap-modal, with header, body and footer.

Now i would add a dropdown-button with dropdown-menu to the modal header. The button is placed correct but if i open the menu the menu is in the middle.[image: modal]

and here the code:

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Max Muster</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
         <div class="dropdown open">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
               <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
               <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
               <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
               <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the second column col-xs-6.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">First column</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">Second column</div>
</div>
```

The start of the second column is on the left hand, so you have to set the class **pull-right**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9nf0afa5/